# Simplest circuit to briefly (100ms) power a 1W LED?

Tags: arduino, led-driver

I am very new to electronics. My project calls for an array (20) of addressable high power LEDs. Each LED needs to be on for at most 100ms. Only one of 20 LEDs is going to be on at any given time(running lights kind of arrangement). I am considering driving those LEDs off single MOSFET per LED with aruduino's digital pin gating the MOSFET. I realize LEDs like constant current but hand-soldering 20 constant current circuits for every LED feels like overkill. What do you think? On a scale of 1 to 10, how sloppy is this approach? Should i also include a beefy current limiting resistor or there is no need given the short duration of pulse?

Comment: Can't you connect them all in parallel to a single current limiting circuit?

Comment: constant current drivers compensate for the LED's heating up and trying to draw more current than cold. If you don't have to worry about heat, then a regulated voltage, 1 common resistor, and ballpark assumptions will suffice.

Comment: If you later want to spruce up your project you can look at individually addressed LED driver ICs.  Less pins and wires, more money. IC number WS2182B can be a starting point.

Comment: The simplest circuit? A charged capacitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Assume you have 20 digital outputs available to drive 20 LEDs
2. So each of them can be independently addressed
3. Since, only one LED is driven at a time you can have single constant current sink circuitry
4. It is like connecting anodes of all the LEDs to the VDD via MOSFETs separately but cathode of all LEDs, tie them together and connect them to constant current sink
5. One simple constant current sink is BJT with emitter resistor..current is set using (voltage at the base minus 0.7 ) / emitter resistor.
   MOSFETs can act like switch to connect to the positive voltage while the BJT constant circuit will control the current for each LEDs..
6. Brightness will drop if two or more LEDs are turned on simultaneously

Comment: This is true. However, putting a resistor in series with the LED will probably work just fine (and produce a constant current) provided that the supply voltage is regulated. If the OP is driving the LED from 5V, then a simple resistor in series will probably be pretty darn constant. But if it is being driven from a battery, or other variable voltage source, then it may be worthwhile to use a constant current circuit such as you describe.

Comment: @mkeith yes I agree. Since OP mentioned constant current circuit, I thought it is better to add it, assuming a variable voltage

Comment: Thank you Umar! i like the idea but i couldn't understand (remember, i am level 0 in electronics) what would happen if all LEDs are off (i need that there is slight delay between turning off LED n and turning on LED n+1). My understanding is that composite load of the array of LEDs https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t24xy1JKzNSZ2BrWqQ8jvYlB0bri54ig/view?usp=sharing would be roughly infinite and that would put constant current portion of circuit beyond its capacity? I mean BJT would be completely saturated.

Comment: Current will be constant nevertheless. But the intensity will go down. Current can't increase beyond set limit using resistor

Answer (score 2):

Philosophically, the question is not whether it is sloppy. The question is, does it satisfy all design requirements? If it does, then it is a good idea. If it doesn't, then you need to continue brainstorming. Parts cost should be reasonable.

You asked whether a beefy resistor is required. Likely not. Because 100 ms is short, your resistor power dissipation rating can be based on the average power in the resistor. You say that you are only on for at most 100 ms, but you don't say how long you will be off for. Let's say it is going to be 0.1s on and 1.9 seconds off. Then the duty cycle, D, will be 0.1 / (0.1 + 1.9) = 0.05.

Pa = Pp * D

Where Pa is the average power, Pp is the peak power, and D is the duty cycle.

Pp = Vr * Ir

Where Vr is the voltage across the resistor and Ir is the current through the resistor during the time that the LED is on. Since you didn't share any details of the circuit, we have no way to know what this is. Hopefully you can calculate it yourself.

I would double whatever you calculate for Pa and choose a resistor based on that power dissipation. For example, if Pa is around 250mW, then use a 500mW resistor. You don't have to exactly double it. That is just a guideline. Just don't cut it too close.

What about efficiency? In general, if the resistor voltage (when on) is lower than the diode voltage, efficiency will be OK. If the resistor voltage is around the same as the diode voltage (or higher), you may need to consider using a DC-DC voltage regulator or DC-DC LED driver to improve efficiency. This is just a guideline. If you want to calculate the efficiency more precisely, ask about that. Most likely if you are driving from 5V, efficiency will be good enough just using a resistor.

Comment: Yes.. I totally agree with the resistor wattage.. I have seen my friends burning up the components in the debug phase.. Where accidentally, LED was on for seconds instead of a planned few ms

Comment: However, note that this assumes a seperate resistor for each LED. You can simplify by having a single resistor (as Umar's answer states) but then it must be sized to handle continous operation.

Comment: High efficiency is gained when the supply voltage is slightly over the max LED Vf.  3.3V is a good supply voltage for a single high power LED.

Comment: @Misunderstood, the closer VCC gets to Vf, the worse the current regulation with changes in VCC or Vf. If it is a white LED, which I have been assuming, I don't think 3.3V is going to be high enough, although I may be wrong, since Vf has been coming down in the last several years.

Comment: Yes, Vf is now typically 2.75V @ test current and 3.1V at max current.  Cree XP-G3 is 3.2V @ 2,000 mA.  Certainly not all are that low, but there are plenty available (the norm) that are.  I do horticulture grow lighting so only deal with high efficacy LEDs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are driving 1-watt LEDs, I would recommend using a current limiter to make sure that you don't get LED meltdown. If you get [thermal runaway](http://www.luxdrive.com/products/what-is-thermal-runaway/), that can happen very quickly.

You could use a single, high-side [current-limited buck regulator](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/CD00172512-116728.pdf) to supply the power, then use one low-side MOSFET for each of the LEDs.

Don't worry about what will happen if all the LEDs are off: the answer is "nothing".

Comment: How do you get thermal runaway when only one LED is powered at any given time?

Comment: @Misunderstood, The OP is talking about 1-watt LEDS. A 1-watt LED makes a lot of heat (in a small space) and a small amount of light. That heat causes the temperature to increase. As the temperature increases, the resistance decreases. If fed with a constant voltage,   the power (V**2/R) will increase, and the temperature will increase further... thermal runaway. Feeding the constant voltage through a resistor will reduce, but not eliminate, the risk of thermal runaway.

Comment: @Misunderstood And sod's law say that at some point the software driving this circuit will crash or go into an infinite loop with one of the LEDs on.

Comment: @TripeHound: been there, done that. Blew six grand worth of prototype laser LEDs *in one day*. Had to put a book down my trousers before going to see my boss....

Comment: Simplest way to avoid this is to scale the resistor such that a LED can be on all the time. Using one common resistor for all LEDs means it will be on basically all the time too. So that should already be able to handle crashed software.

Comment: First point, LEDs should NEVER be powered with CV.  When resistance decreases wattage (heat) decreases.  How low would the temperature coefficient need to be  for your described runaway scenario?  The lowest I have seen is -0.006V/°C.  Second, thermal runaway describes the current imbalance caused by thermal characteristics  between parallel strings of LEDs powered by a single CC source.   BTW: Current (2018) high power white and blue LEDs generate ~70% light and ~30% heat, not more heat than light.